# In bloc test the add event doesnot work when decodeImageFromList is used inside bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Bloc test fails to call an event if we use `decodeImageFromList`

We had to get the width and height of an image `file` inside bloc for that we are using `decodeImageFromList` but after that when we `add` another event, that event doesn't execute while writing **blocTest**.

Dummy code:

```
 Stream<OurState> _mapEventOne(File file) async* {
    final decodedImage =
        await decodeImageFromList(await pickedImage.readAsBytes());
/// This add event is not working
    add(
      EventTwo(
        width: decodedImage.width,
        height: decodedImage.height,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: are you working with state or you are working with File object.

Comment: I didn't get what do you meant, I'm working with Bloc and the File object is received as an Event attribute @DanielAidoo

Comment: oh ok,will research more and get back to you